# Zipkin & Sleuth, Tracer missing the createSpan method

Tags: java, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am following the tutorial for creating tracing application `zipkin` and `sleuth` but I am having some trouble. I cannot create a span. The problem is that the method does not exist. Also I cannot find the import for the tracer.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer;

@Component 
public class  Test {

  @Autowired
  Tracer tracer;

  public void test (){
     Span newSpan = tracer.createSpan("test");
     //business logic
     tracer.close(newSpan);
  }



}
```

Why is the implementation above not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an old implementation. Below I have modified your code to work:

```
import brave.Tracing;
import brave.Span;

@Component 
public class  Test {

  @Autowired
  Tracing tracing;

  public void test (){
     Span span = tracing.tracer().nextSpan().name("name");
     //business logic
     span.finish();
  }
}
```

For more information check this link: https://gist.github.com/marcingrzejszczak/d3c15a0c11dda71970e42c513c9c0e09